# How to resolve the "Verify the message's origin in this cross-origin communication" vulnerability in sonarqube.?

Tags: javascript, security, sonarqube, xss

My project runs the sonarqube scan for each build.

In the line  `self.addEventListener`, I have the *"Verify the message's origin in this cross-origin communication."* vulnerability in scan results.

My application is getting loaded in an iframe.

The code snippet is as follows:-

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    switch (e.data.cmd) {
        case "init":
            _initializeTimer(e.data.timeIntervalInSec);
            break;
        case "resetTimer":
            clearTimeout(self.sessionTimer);
            _initializeTimer(e.data.timeIntervalInSec);
            break;
        default:
            self.postMessage({
                status: "error",
                info: "please send a valid command"
            });
            break;
    }
```

What is the potential cause of this vulnerability ?

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: while I'm not sure what sonarqube is expecting, the event has a property called `origin` that you can check to make sure it's from the same domain. In addition, have a look at the iframe itself, iframe's have a `refererpolicy` option. The idea is that your page could be embedded in an iframe by someone else on another domain

Answer (score 3):

According to this resource https://sonarsource.atlassian.net/browse/RSPEC-2819, you need to check the domain the message was posted from

```js
self.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org") // Compliant
    return;
      
  console.log(event.data)
});
```

And also add a specific domain to your postMessage function if you used a wildcard '*'

```js
self.postMessage("secret", "*");
```